# Sublime Text 3 & Perforce Plugin

Tags: perforce, sublimetext3

I'm using a newly installed Linux Mint and attempting to develop with Sublime Text 3.

- I've installed p4v, p4 and ST3.
- I've created a P4CONFIG in the workspace folder that contains the `P4PORT`, `P4CLIENT` and `P4USER` variables and their appropriate values.
- I've added the Perforce.sublime-settings files to my `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User` folder that contains the other ST3 plugin settings.
- The settings include `"perforce_auto_checkout_on_save": true`.
- I've gone to terminal in the relevant folder I am trying to edit and ran the `p4 info` command and it seems to recognize the server and workspace I am trying to access.

No matter what I do, I am still unable to login using the `Perforce: Login` command and the appropriate password. As a result, when I save, it doesn't check out the files.

Please help me get this working. I really want this to work.

Thanks

Comment: Do you get an error from the login attempt? What does the error say? What version of the server are you running? If it's a recent version, have your server admin turn server logging up to level 4 and then examine the server logs for errors corresponding to your commands.

Comment: No errors. Simply no output at all. I don't think it's even making a request to the server.

Comment: Is the server on the same machine? Or on a separate machine? Perhaps a network firewall is preventing your machine from connecting to the server?

Comment: Server is on a different machine. I've gotten the plugin to work on a Windows partition on the same computer, and I can still connect to the perforce server both via command line and via a P4V client.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a mac OSX (Yosemite).  p4 was installed in /usr/local/bin.  .bash_profile included same in $PATH.  p4 would execute from fresh bash session.

Problem was resolved when I made a symbolic link in /usr/bin:

```
$ cd /usr/bin
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/p4 p4
$ ls -l p4
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  17 Jul 26 17:05 p4 -> /usr/local/bin/p4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `p4` in a non-default location the binary won't be found and any plugin commands will fail. (Unfortunately the error reporting by the plugin is misleading, saying that the file is not under the client's root.)

On OSX, the Perforce plugin prepends its shell environment with `.bash_profile`, so you have a chance to tell the shell where to go to find `p4` by being explicit there:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH
```

I had the same issue, and after adding the line above (I have `p4` under `/user/local/bin`) the plugin began operating normally.